# Quilljs Downlaod .docx

Tags: javascript, php, quill

I'm creating a online document creator as a feature of my site using Quilljs. I have it set up and was wondering if there is a way to download the document after it is typed up? Maybe using php or javascript and Preferably in; .doc, .docx, .txt or any other basic text formats. If there is another framework like this and it has this feature then please let me know.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quill content is represented by [Delta](http://quilljs.com/docs/delta/) format which is a simple list of insert/retain/delete operations.

You can [get the HTML](https://github.com/quilljs/quill/issues/903#issuecomment-243844178) on the client side with:

```
document.querySelector(".ql-editor").innerHTML
```

You can use other tools to convert the HTML to docx on the server side.